# Pandas styled tables hosting in Figure Plot

Tags: pandas, plot

Good evening,

I created "Several" styled DataFrame tables from SQL query with footnotes and would like to create a subplot figure to host these tables in a report format.

Table Code is as follows:

```
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query (sqlq, connection)
df = sql_query

df['Product_Group'].loc[df['Product_Group'] == 'Pizzas'] = '*Pizzas'
df['Product_Group'].loc[df['Product_Group'] == 'Tratorria'] = '**Tratorria'

df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda x : '{:,}'.format(x))+ ' EGP';
df['Quantity'] = df['Quantity'].apply(lambda x : "{:,}".format(x))+ ' Units';

df = df.style.set_caption((
                            f'''Quantity and Sales broken down by <u>Product Group</u>.<br>
                            The data is filtered on <u>Order Date</u> and <u>Branch Name</u>.<br>
                            The Branch Name filter keeps <strong>{branch[2]}</strong>.<br>
                            * Pizzas Includes: <strong>(Pizza Meat,Pizza Vegetables, Pizza Turkey, Pizza Seafood, Appetizers)</strong><br>
                            ** Trattoria Includes: <strong>(Pasta,Risotto)</strong>'''
                          ))

dfstyle = [dict(selector="th", props=[('font-size', '18px')]),\
           dict(selector="td", props=[('font-size', '16px')]),\
           dict(selector="caption",props=[("text-align", "left"),("caption-side", "bottom"),
                       ("font-size", "14px"),("color", 'black')]
               )
          ]
df = df.set_table_styles(dfstyle)
df = df.apply(bold_lastrow)
df = df.set_properties(subset=['Quantity','Price'], **{'width': '400px'})
df = df.set_properties(subset=['Product_Group'], **{'text-align': 'left','font-weight': 'bold'})
df = df.set_properties(**{'font-family': 'Century Gothic'})
df = df.hide_index()
```

HTML Render to recreate table:

```
'<style  type="text/css" >\n    #T_04faa_ th {\n          font-size: 18px;\n    }    #T_04faa_ td {\n          font-size: 16px;\n    }    #T_04faa_ caption {\n          text-align: left;\n          caption-side: bottom;\n          font-size: 14px;\n          color: black;\n    }#T_04faa_row0_col0,#T_04faa_row1_col0,#T_04faa_row2_col0,#T_04faa_row3_col0,#T_04faa_row4_col0{\n            text-align:  left;\n            font-weight:  bold;\n            font-family:  Century Gothic;\n        }#T_04faa_row0_col1,#T_04faa_row0_col2,#T_04faa_row1_col1,#T_04faa_row1_col2,#T_04faa_row2_col1,#T_04faa_row2_col2,#T_04faa_row3_col1,#T_04faa_row3_col2,#T_04faa_row4_col1,#T_04faa_row4_col2{\n            width:  400px;\n            font-family:  Century Gothic;\n        }#T_04faa_row5_col0{\n            font-weight:  bold;\n            text-align:  left;\n            font-weight:  bold;\n            font-family:  Century Gothic;\n        }#T_04faa_row5_col1,#T_04faa_row5_col2{\n            font-weight:  bold;\n            width:  400px;\n            font-family:  Century Gothic;\n        }</style><table id="T_04faa_" ><caption>Quantity and Sales broken down by <u>Product Group</u>.<br>\n                            The data is filtered on <u>Order Date</u> and <u>Branch Name</u>.<br>\n                            The Branch Name filter keeps <strong>All Branches</strong>.<br>\n                            * Pizzas Includes: <strong>(Pizza Meat,Pizza Vegetables, Pizza Turkey, Pizza Seafood, Appetizers)</strong><br>\n                            ** Trattoria Includes: <strong>(Pasta,Risotto)</strong></caption><thead>    <tr>        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >Product_Group</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >Quantity</th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >Price</th>    </tr></thead><tbody>\n                <tr>\n                                <td id="T_04faa_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >None</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >10.0 Units</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >250.0 EGP</td>\n            </tr>\n            <tr>\n                                <td id="T_04faa_row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >Beverages</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >301.0 Units</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >10,214.0 EGP</td>\n            </tr>\n            <tr>\n                                <td id="T_04faa_row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >Others</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >95.0 Units</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >7,315.0 EGP</td>\n            </tr>\n            <tr>\n                                <td id="T_04faa_row3_col0" class="data row3 col0" >*Pizzas</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row3_col1" class="data row3 col1" >144.0 Units</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row3_col2" class="data row3 col2" >20,830.0 EGP</td>\n            </tr>\n            <tr>\n                                <td id="T_04faa_row4_col0" class="data row4 col0" >**Tratorria</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row4_col1" class="data row4 col1" >43.0 Units</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row4_col2" class="data row4 col2" >6,715.0 EGP</td>\n            </tr>\n            <tr>\n                                <td id="T_04faa_row5_col0" class="data row5 col0" >Grand Total</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row5_col1" class="data row5 col1" >593.0 Units</td>\n                        <td id="T_04faa_row5_col2" class="data row5 col2" >45,324.0 EGP</td>\n            </tr>\n    </tbody></table>'
```

Yet I still can't figure out how to host this "Styler Object" in a subplot figure to export as a A4 report.

EDIT 2:

Jupyter renders the styled DF as follows:

[image]

Yet HTML Render with df.render() displays the df as follows:

[image]

Which is obviously incorrect formatting thus refraining me from continuing to research embedding the output HTML to render the report.

Comment: Styler.render() is deprecated in most latest pandas. Use Styler.to_html instead

Comment: @Attack68 AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_html'

Comment: you are using an old version of pandas

Comment: @Attack68 Did upgrade and exported as HTML yet still don't know how to compile several HTML reports in one page. how to reuse exported HTML